# How to fix onload function with Conditional If and else

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

My  problem here is the fact that I don't know how to do the if statement. for onload page I want when the id is #lang_link\[fr\] directly run function ParseJSON1 and when my id #lang_link\[en\] run function ParseJSON2
I want to fix this:

```
window.onload = function runAtLoadTime() {
    if(document.getElementsById('#lang_link\\[fr\\]').value = 'fr' ){
        ParseJSON1();
    } 
    else 
    {
        ParseJSON2();
    }   
}
```

to call:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#lang_link\\[fr\\]').click(function (){
        ParseJSON1('fr');
    });
    $('#lang_link\\[en\\]').click(function (){
        ParseJSON2('en');
    });
});
```

code to run:

```
function ParseJSON1() {  
    var JSONObject = {  
        "footerboutiques": "Sourav french",  
        "boutiquelink": "https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp",
        "footerrestaurants": "Kayal",  
        "Restaurantslink": "https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp",
        "footeracces": 24,  
        "acceslink": "https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp",
        "footeraerogare": "123456" ,
        "aerogarelink": "https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp", 
    };  
    var Value = eval(JSONObject);  
    document.getElementById("footerboutiques").innerHTML = Value.footerboutiques; 
    document.getElementById("boutiquelink").href = Value.boutiquelink; 
    document.getElementById("footerrestaurants").innerHTML = Value.footerrestaurants; 
    document.getElementById("Restaurantslink").href = Value.Restaurantslink;  
    document.getElementById("footeracces").innerHTML = Value.footeracces;
    document.getElementById("acceslink").href = Value.acceslink; 
    document.getElementById("footeraerogare").innerHTML = Value.footeraerogare;  
    document.getElementById("aerogarelink").href = Value.aerogarelink; 
}  
    
function ParseJSON2() {  
    var JSONObject = {  
        "footerboutiques": "Sourav2 english",  
        "boutiquelink": "https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById",
        "footerrestaurants": "Kayal2",  
        "Restaurantslink": "https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById",
        "footeracces": 242,  
        "acceslink": "https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById",
        "footeraerogare": "1234562" ,
        "aerogarelink": "https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById",  
    };  
    var Value = eval(JSONObject);  
    document.getElementById("footerboutiques").innerHTML = Value.footerboutiques;  
    document.getElementById("boutiquelink").href = Value.boutiquelink; 
    document.getElementById("footerrestaurants").innerHTML = Value.footerrestaurants; 
    document.getElementById("Restaurantslink").href = Value.Restaurantslink;  
    document.getElementById("footeracces").innerHTML = Value.footeracces;  
    document.getElementById("acceslink").href = Value.acceslink; 
    document.getElementById("footeraerogare").innerHTML = Value.footeraerogare ;
    document.getElementById("aerogarelink").href = Value.aerogarelink; 
}
```

Comment: `........value = 'fr')` <---- you are setting the value

Comment: `var Value = eval(JSONObject);` <--- why are you evaling an Object????

Comment: to return to page html

Comment: For *onload page when the id is #lang_link\[fr\] directly run function ParseJSON1* use `$(function() { if ($("#lang_link\\[fr\\]").length) ParseJSON1(); else ParseJSON2();`